# Apache: Running ghost on a subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, proxypass, ghost-blog

Does anyone have hints for running **ghost** on a subdomain with the following apache conf:

```
<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>

UseCanonicalName Off

VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0/httpdocs

</IfModule>
```

(I do not have any **sites-available**)
I tried **ProxyPass** but that is not working properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ghost subdomain in Apache with CentOS](http://serverfault.com/questions/566526/ghost-subdomain-in-apache-with-centos).

Comment: I don't think so.